# StringTokenizer says java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

When I run my code using `BufferedReader` class as well as util class and initialising the variables outside the `StringTokenizer` using `BufferedReader` class then it works but when I use this it breaks and I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error as I input the first String s(in the code).

```
import java.util.*;

class spamclas
{
public static void main() 
{

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=0,b=0;
    int t=sc.nextInt();
    while(t>0)
    {
        String s=sc.next();
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s);
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }

        System.out.println("a   b"+a+"   "+b);
        t--;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What input did you try ?

Comment: @azro  t=3  s =1 1 As I enter the value of s for the first time it breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `st.hasMoreTokens()` look if there is at least *one* more element next and you call `st.nextToken()` twice

---

So in case there is only one more element, the condition will be `true` but the second `st.nextToken()` will find anything

Because you give `1 1` to `sc.next()`, you `String s` will be only `1` (default separator of `next()` is space), so there is only one digit, and second `nextToken()` will faill

Youd better use `sc.nextLine()` and check for each digit with 2 `if` :

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());        // nextLine here too to consume return char
while (t > 0) {
  String s = sc.nextLine();
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
  a = b = 0;
  if (st.hasMoreTokens()) { a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); }else{ a=0; }  //line 18
  if (st.hasMoreTokens()) { b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); }else{ b=0; }  //line 19
  System.out.println("a : " + a + ", b : " + b);
  t--;
}
```

---

Tips : line 18&19 can be written with ternary operator :

```
a = st.hasMoreTokens() ? Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) : 0;
b = st.hasMoreTokens() ? Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) : 0;
```

Comment: Now when I ran the code the program takes no input for the first time when the loop works but for the second time it asks for String s, What can I do to solve that ?

Comment: @amethyststan Did you change the line for init of `int t ` as I give ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Don´t worry

The problem is that when it reaches this line.

```
b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

It is empty.

Because you put the .nextToken() in a it is now empty.